# Can't use big size QByteArray as QString

Tags: c++, qt

I have big `char*` object. When I write this array to file, the size of this file is 63.7 MB. I receive `QByteArray` object from this object like this

```
QByteArray outputDataByteArray(outputData, outputSize);
```

If I try to send this object to function as `QString` parameter, I receive

> Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

While debugging I noticed that it crash after calling function with this array as input parameter, but does not come in this function.

I tried something like this

```
outputDataByteArray.append("\0");
```

according to documentation information, that

> Warning: A byte array created with `fromRawData()` is not null-terminated, unless the raw data contains a 0 character at position size. While that does not matter for `QDataStream` or functions like `indexOf()`, passing the byte array to a function accepting a `const char *` expected to be `'\0'`-terminated will fail.

But it didn't help me.

On small size of data all work fine.

Edition:

This is some function I receive `QBytearray` in it (all work fine):

```
uncompress(const QByteArray &inputByteArray, bool *ok)
{
if (ok != NULL)
    *ok = false;

const char *inputData = inputByteArray.data();

char *outputData = NULL;
qint64 outputSize   = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK_COUNT_MAX; i++)
{
    const int outputSizeMax = CHUNKSIZE * (i + 1);
    outputData = new char[outputSizeMax];


    outputSize = LZ4_decompress_safe_withPrefix64k(inputData, outputData, inputByteArray.length(), outputSizeMax);

    if (outputSize < 0)
    {
        delete [] outputData;
        outputData = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

if (outputData == NULL)
    return QByteArray();

QFile file("C:/Users/HOME/file.txt");
if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
{
    file.write(outputData, outputSize);
}
file.close();

QByteArray outputDataByteArray(outputData, outputSize);

outputDataByteArray.append("\0");

delete [] outputData;

if (ok != NULL)
    *ok = true;

return outputDataByteArray;
```

}

But, if I try to to call another function with this array as parameter:

```
parse(outputDataByteArray, ok);
```

I receive what I wrote above.

Addition:
It does not come in this function but defination of function that i send QByteArray as parameter:

```
parse(const QString &json, bool &success)
{
    success = true;
    if(!json.isNull() || !json.isEmpty())
    {
            QString data = json;

            int index = 0;


            QVariant value = Json::parseValue(data, index, success);


            return value;
    }
    else
    {
        return QVariant();
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly post your code in your question.

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: What's the signature of `LZ4_decompress_safe_withPrefix64k`?  I'm guessing but... if it's a 'C' function and it's supposed to assign to `outputData` then shouldn't the second arg be `&outputData`?

Comment: The [documentation](https://grass.osgeo.org/programming7/lz4_8c.html#a2ea4e15e70c6c9fb4c33c2e47bdf6c57) would suggest that it's up to the caller to allocate memory for `outputData` *before* calling `LZ4_decompress_safe_withPrefix64k`.

Comment: sorry i'm new on this site. i edited my question and i'm doing allocating of memory to output object

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `LZ4_decompress_safe_withPrefix64k` with:

```
char *outputData = NULL;
```

And, this function's definitions is like this:

```
int LZ4_decompress_safe_withPrefix64k(const char* source, char* dest, int compressedSize, int maxOutputSize)
{
    return LZ4_decompress_generic(source, dest, compressedSize, maxOutputSize, endOnInputSize, full, 0, withPrefix64k, (BYTE*)dest - 64 KB, NULL, 64 KB);
}
```

And, the definition of `LZ4_decompress_generic` doesn't have any allocation code for your output buffer. See [definition](https://grass.osgeo.org/programming7/lz4_8c_source.html#l01110) of `LZ4_decompress_generic`.

It is simply typecasted in `line # 1129`:

```
BYTE* op = (BYTE*) dest;
```

And, it is further used throughout the definition of this function e.g. `memcpy`, `LZ4_wildCopy`, `LZ4_copy8`, etc.

So, it's invalid memory that is being pointed by your output buffer pointer. You need to allocate its memory before passing it to the function. In addition to it, you need validate a pointer before passing it to other function. You may use `asserts` or `if` checks to validate this.

Hope that would help.

Comment: sorry i'm new on this site. i edited my question and i'm doing allocating of memory to output object

Comment: @Leto: You need to isolate a couple of things to test your scenario. First, just comment that function call to the library function and then observe the behavior the other code. If there's no problem then you'll be sure that the all code is working fine. From my observation, `LZ4_decompress_generic` (https://grass.osgeo.org/programming7/lz4_8c_source.html#l01110) doesn't append any kind of null character to make it a C-style string. You need to validate that before creating a `QByteArray` from it. From your code, it's not apparent what the `inputByteArray` initial state is.

Comment: @Leto: Did you try to debug using breakpoints? Any findings? What is your RAM size? Your OS?

Comment: RAM 8Gb 
OS Windows 7.
The problem is only exist on big size data. confuse this moment.
After debugging on big size data i noticed, that outputData is readable, because i wrote it to file and checked it there.  This message
"Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function" i receive only then calling another function with output data as parameter, but it doesn't come in to this function. seems problem in converting from bytearray to string

Comment: @Leto: Can you try to `reserve()` with `QByteArray` before entering data? I had a similar problem in the past and reserving memory before use solved that.

Comment: @Leto: Something like this: http://ideone.com/1OFMfd. You can simply create a QByteArray in advance and reserve its memory and then you can pass its data pointer to the function. It'll be filled with the data. You have to make provision for enough data that may store in it.

Comment: it is doesn't help me

Comment: @Leto: What is the signature of `parse` function?

Comment: parse(const QString &json, bool &success)

Comment: Can you add the definition of `parse` in your question? Or any other portion of your code which is directly linked with this problem.

Comment: @Leto: The parse is taking `QString` as first argument so your `QByteArray` is first converted into a `QString` using its respective constructor. You should change that to `parse( const QByteArray& json, bool &success )`. Further, it is simple byte array, right? You are treating it inside function as JSON. Why is that? Is there some kind of conversion to JSON that is not there in the code?

Comment: it is not byte array, it is array with readable decompressed result of query.